# Cast an object into a generic type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection

I'd like to perform a cast like the one below:

```
if (prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ObjectSet<>))
       {
         if (prop.Name.StartsWith("NV_"))
           {
             var nvLookupTable = (prop.GetValue(context) as ObjectSet<>);
             // I know the above statement is wrong. I'd like to cast
             // it as an ObjectSet<NV_Something> where NV_Something is the name
             // of the database table
```

I forget these things every few years/months/weeks, esp. when I am under pressure.

Comment: As I added in my comment on your other question, you can't (and you should almost certainly use a cast instead of `as` anyway). You haven't said anything about what you're trying to *do* with the value afterwards, which makes it hard to help.

Comment: You cannot do that in a single statement: if you want a statically typed `var`, you will need to use a chain of `if`-`then`-`else`. Otherwise you can use `dynamic`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thank you. Sorry, I might have posted this question while you were typing the comment in my previous question. I've used reflection for now. I just wanted to read property values from the ObjectSet<T>. I thought a strongly-typed object would be nice. Appears I thought wrong. Have a vague recollection of having a built a wrapper around reflection to get a strongly typed interface to a reflected run-time object. Thanks much.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2: *What* property values? Again, please be precise. (The fewer rounds of clarification that are required, the quicker you'll get a solution.) Also, please say which version of C# and .NET you're using.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I think I'm not thinking straight because of the pressure. I was wrong again. I wanted to get an ObjectContext object, and search it for all ObjectSet<T>'s where T.Name started with "Foo". I've got this far now. Now, I want to read each element in the underlying IEnumerable<T> of the ObjectSet<T> and then read the properties of each item in that IEnumerable<T>. I'm still stuck figuring out how I could get execute the enumerator using reflection.

Comment: I am using C# 4.0 with .NET 4.0.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you. I changed the code to use `dynamic`. Not that safe I know, but I had a deadline and this was a one-off thing to load some initial data into the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my crystal ball is in for service. So my guess of what you are trying to is either :

1. Dynamically access a a property.
2. Dynamically call a generic method
3. Dynamically call instantiate an object

1)

```
dynamic dObj = bla;
dObj.Prop
```

2)    Dynamic generic method

```
 // example looks close to yout issue, (checking removed for brevity) 
 // call method GetRespository<poco>  dynamically on any object that implements ILuw
 // the result passed back is also dynamic.  For obvious reasons.    

 public static dynamic GetDynamicRepository(ILuw iLuw, string pocoFullName)  {
        //null checks removed for demo....
        var pocoType = Type.GetType(pocoFullName);
        MethodInfo method = typeof(ILuw).GetMethod("GetRepository");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(pocoType);

        var IRepOfT = generic.Invoke(iLuw, null);
        dynamic repOfT = IRepOfT;
        return repOfT;
    }
```

3)  Dynamic generic Instance creation, example is repository instantiation

```
public class RepositoryFactory<TPoco> where TPoco : BaseObjectConstraintHere {
    public IRepositoryBase<TPoco> GetRepository(DbContext context) {
       // get the Pocotype for generic repository instantiation
        var pocoTypes = new[] {typeof (TPoco)};  // but you can also extend to  <T,U>
        Type repBaseType = GetRepositoryType(typeof(TPoco)); // get the best matching Class type
        // now make one of those please..
        IRepositoryBase<TPoco> repository = InstantiateRepository(context, repBaseType, pocoTypes);

       return repository;
    }


    private Type GetRepositoryType(Type T) { 
        if (ConditionX) {
            return typeof(RepositoryX<>);
        }
        return typeof (RepositoryY<>);
    }  // note you can return Repository<,>   if the type requires 2 generic params


    // Now instantiate Class Type with the Generic type passing in a constructor param  
    private IRepositoryBase<TPoco> InstantiateRepository(BosBaseDbContext context, Type repType, params Type[] pocoTypes) {

        Type repGenericType = repType.MakeGenericType(pocoTypes);
        object repInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(repGenericType, context);
        return (IRepositoryBase<TPoco>)repInstance;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you. I just used `dynamic`.